# Lagrangian for small oscillations

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, approximations, coupled-oscillators

For a [double pendulum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_pendulum) we can consider 2 generalised coordinates $\theta_1$ (angle between first mass and vertical axis) and $\theta_2$ (angle between second mass and vertical axis).

The Lagrangian to this system is:

$$L=T-V.$$

I found [here](http://steadyserverpages.com/steadystate/CourseWork/721/hw6cm.pdf) , that for small oscillations we can assume the following approximations:

For $T$: $\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)\approx 1 $ (working in zeroth order)

For $V$: $\cos(\theta_1)\approx 1-\theta_1^2/2$, as for  $\cos(\theta_2)$ (working in second order)

Why can we work with different orders on the same system for small oscillations?

If we assume an $n$ order, shouldn't we maintain  that order independently if it's $T$ or $V$?

Comment: I don't believe there is a rigorous reason, or any reason at all except "this is easier to solve, and the result isn't *that* wrong".

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which book?

Comment: http://www.steadyserverpages.com/steadystate/CourseWork/721/hw6cm.pdf

Comment: This is a problem from Goldstein. I don't know who wrote the resolution, but he/she shows credibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The small oscillation approximation considers terms in the Lagrangian to quadratic order in $\theta_i$ and $\dot{\theta}_i$. The reason to only work to zeroth order in $\theta_i$ in one term is because the pertinent term in the [Lagrangian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_pendulum) is already quadratic in $\dot{\theta}_i$.